# How to sync the real time SMS data from Marketing cloud to Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sendsmsactivity

I know that Email's tracking data syncing from MC to Salesforce. Is there any way to sync the real time SMS data from Marketing cloud to Salesforce?

If yes, kindly provide the required steps with example?

Answer (score 2):

This is not done by default or can't be achieved easily with any out-of-the-box feature.

Currently the simplest method of doing this is by including Ampscript in your SMS code to create a record in Salesforce using the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject.html) function.

This will be really closest to real-time as you can get, but you need to have discussions in your company on which object you would want the SMS to be stored, so no example can be provided.

This also has the downside that it will completely change how you create SMS - if you want to push the whole text of the text message into SF, you will need to have this text stored in a single Ampscript variable.

If you would accept delays (up to 1 hour with a single automation or more often with many), you could write automations that push the data into Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks Rafal for your inputs. Also we have to sync (real time) the SMS Opt-In & Opt-Out info from Marketing Cloud (after updating the MC details) to SFDC. Is there any solution to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @venkat It all depends on how your opt-in and opt-outs work. If those are standard SFMC based solutions using ampscript / solutions, you could add code that uses the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() function to update corresponging Salesforce fields as well

Comment: thanks @RafałWolsztyniak for the answer! Just to clarify: I am noticing `marketing cloud` installed package sobjects `Mobile Send` and `SMS Junction` - these imply some kind of sync from Marketing Cloud back to SFDC CRM but are you saying this is just not the case?